# nginx .htaccess in two diffrent folders

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I have a script that has 2 .htaccess files. The fist .htaccess file is in the root directory, and the second is in a folder under the root directory called upload.

However, what I can not figure out is what would be the proper way to configure nginx to apply the proper rules to the .htaccess file in the upload folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx does not support .htaccess files.

You will have to move the configuration over to the nginx configuration folder.

nginx syntax is fairly straightforward once you get the hang of it, and their documentation is pretty good. And there are a *lot* of resources online on how to implement a given feature on Apache in nginx instead.

You may be able to use a [.htaccess -> nginx converter like this one](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) to make all necessary changes.

Then, instead of storing it in that directory, you add it under a location in your config.

Let's say you have an .htaccess file in `/var/sites/example.com/foo`

Convert it to nginx and then store it in `/etc/nginx/includes` (or wherever your nginx config folder is) as `foo.access`.

Then you would include it in the main config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /foo {
        include includes/foo.access;
    }
}
```

Add a location entry for each .htaccess file.

If you have limited access to the config folder (if, for example, you only have FTP access to your site under a shared server), you can put the nginx-compatible files in your webroot and ask the server admin to soft-link from within the includes directory:

```
ln -s /var/sites/example.org/foo.access /etc/nginx/includes/foo.access
```

Since they're in the webroot and thus publicly accessible, you'd want to add this to the main config:

```
location ~ (\.access) {
    return 403;
}
```

That way anyone trying to access the files will get blocked from doing so.

Comment: So currently for the .htaccess file in the root folder, I have added the rewrite rules to the server block configuration in site-available.  So I should take what I have put in sites-available and make a file called *.access. Then what should I do for the .htaccess file that is specific to the upload folder?

Comment: I would recommend creating an nginx-format .access file for  each .htaccess file, and include them in the config file for the site.